# Why is angular flex layout not working with angular ~13.3.0?

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, dependency-management, angular-flex-layout

## Problem statement:

Angular flex-layout compilation problem when adding angular flex layout to an angular ~13.3.x project as import to the `app.module.ts`

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new angular project (with angular version ~13.3.x) `ng new <projectname>`
2. Add flex layout dependency `npm install --save @angular/flex-layout@13.0.0-beta.38`
3. Serve project `ng s` (no issues)
4. Add import to flex layout module within the `app.module.ts` file:

`import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';`

5. **Compilation fails with:**

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/index.d.ts:37:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires 6 type argument(s).
37     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<Dir, "[dir]", ["dir"], { "dir": "dir"; }, { "change": "dirChange"; }, never, never, false>;
```

### Question:

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error just trying to get Angular Material to work on a new project. Make sure the following packages are up-to-date, it worked for me:

Typescript
Angular/Material
Graphql

Also, I reverted back to angular/cdk version 13.0 (I was previously using 14)

I'm not sure exactly which one fixed the issue, but installing and updating all of them did the trick.